# Dapper - passing child objects as query parameter

Tags: c#, dapper

Is there a way to pass child or multiple objects to Dapper as query parameter, when they have properties with the same name?

For example, if I have these classes:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}

class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to execute this query:

```
connect.QueryFirst<Result>("select :Id Id, :Name Name, :City_Id City_Id, :City_Name City_Name from dual", personParams);
```

The only way I managed to do it without reflection was passing the first object and then adding the other properties one by one:

```
var personParams = new DynamicParameters(person);
personParams.AddDynamicParams(new { City_Id = person.City.Id, City_name = person.City.Name });
```

But on the database there are hundreds of tables, some of them with more than a hundred columns, and I need to split them into multiple classes. So passing the parameters one by one would be improductive.

I tried adding the parameters to a temporary bag and then adding a prefix to each one, something like this:

```
static DynamicParameters GetParameters(object mainEntity, object otherEntities)
{
    var allParams = new DynamicParameters(mainEntity);
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(otherEntities))
    {
        object obj = descriptor.GetValue(otherEntities);
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters(obj);
        foreach (var paramName in parameters.ParameterNames)
        {
            var value = parameters.Get<object>(paramName);
            allParams.Add($"{descriptor.Name}{paramName}", value);
        }
    }
    return allParams;
}
```

But it doesn't work because Dapper only populates the parameters when the command is executing, not when the DynamicParamters is created.

I wanted to avoid reflection because Dapper is very good at it, and my code would probably perform much worse. Is there a way to do it or is reflection my only option?

Comment: You only need to go one level deep?

Comment: @Magnus One level would probably work in 90% of the cases, so it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I think you are going to have to write it yourself using reflection. Don't think there is any dapper magic for your case.